# Sitecore 10.2 salesforce xConnect Client Endpoint

Tags: xconnect, integration

[image][image]I am trying to connect Sitecore to salesfore during `xConnect Client` Endpoint I am getting this error I have given this following details also I tried to browse `xconncet.dev.local` from `IIS` in browser site is not reached showing[image]

Comment: Add this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved when I compared Host file server name with IIS Binding server name was not matching –